# Uploading file get error "he "C:\xampp\tmp\phpC108.tmp" file does not exist or is not readable." Laravel 6.2

Tags: laravel

i have a Module upload file . and its working normally at laravel 5.8 . ut i update this laravel to 6.2 version its having error like this :

> The "C:\xampp\tmp\phpC108.tmp" file does not exist or is not readable.

this is my upload store function

```
public function store_cuti(Request $request)
{
   
    $this->validate($request,[
        
    ] );

    if($request->hasfile('berkas'))

    {   
    $file = $request->file('berkas');
        $extension = $request->berkas->getClientOriginalExtension();  //Get Image Extension
        $fileName =  uniqid().'.'.$extension;  //Concatenate both to get FileName (eg: file.jpg)
        $file->move(public_path().'/file_cuti/', $fileName);  
        $data = $fileName;  
    }


    $users = new Data_cuti;
    $users->user_id              = $request->user_id ;
    $users->nama_surat           = $request->nama_surat ;
    $users->tgl_surat            = $request->tgl_surat ;
    $users->durasi_cuti          = $request->durasi_cuti ;
    $users->tgl_mulai            = $request->tgl_mulai ;
    $users->status               = $request->status ;
    $users->berkas               = $data;
    $cuti = DB::table('users')->select('users.cuti')->where('id',$request->user_id)->first();
        if(Input::get('durasi_cuti') > $cuti){
            return redirect()->back();
        }
        elseif($cuti > Input::get('durasi_cuti')){
            DB::table('users')->where('id', $request->user_id)->decrement('cuti' , Input::get('durasi_cuti'));
        }
        else{
            return ('error , tidak ada input');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
   
    dd($data);
    // $users->save();
    // return redirect ('cuti_pegawai')->with('success', 'Input Succes');
    

}
```

someone have a solution for this problem ?

## UPDATE....

i know this problem .  this problem is from line

```
$cuti = DB::table('users')->select('users.cuti')->where('id',$request->user_id)->first();
        if(Input::get('durasi_cuti') > $cuti){
            return redirect()->back();
        }
        elseif($cuti > Input::get('durasi_cuti')){
            DB::table('users')->where('id', $request->user_id)->decrement('cuti' , Input::get('durasi_cuti'));
        }
        else{
            return ('error , tidak ada input');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
```

if i delete this line its work normally . but i need this line to update some data in another field table

Answer (score 0):

`use Imagick` at the top of your Controller.

Comment: no , i think this prolem is the decrement . decrement is failur script i think

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using
$file->move(public_path().'/file_cuti/', $fileName);

use 
$file->storeAs(public_path().'/file_cuti/', $fileName);